# Probability regarding success and failure...

Tags: probability

I have a question....

---

A man can hit a target once in $4$ shots, if he fires $4$ shots in succession, what is the probability that he will hit his target?

---

I did this,
probability of hit = $\frac14$, 
so four times = $\frac{1}{256}$

but answer is $\frac{175}{256}$..(may/ may not)(this book has lots of errors in answers)

How to deal with these kinds of problems...

Comment: Note that $\frac{1}{4} > \frac{1}{256}$.  Does it make sense that he is more likely to hit the target in one shot than in four?

Comment: The wording on these questions is important.  I think this question is asking the probability of the target being hit at least once.  (In this case it is easier to determine the complementary probability of the target not being hit at all.)  You answered the question of what is the probability of the target being hit every time.

Comment: $\frac{1}{256}$ would be the probability that he hits the target all four times. Not the chance that he will hit the target.

Answer (score 1):

Let $p$ be the chance of hitting the target: $p = 1/4$.

Let $q$ be the chance of not hitting it: $q = 1-p = 3/4$.

**Easy but long way:**

For a succes, one of this scenarios is valid:

He can hit it on the first shot. The chance for that is $p$.

Miss the first and hit on the second shot. The chance for that is $qp$.

Miss the first and second but hit on the third shot. The chance for that is $q^2p$.

Miss the first three but hit on the fourth shot. The chance for that is $q^3p$.

So the chance of success would be:

$$p + qp + q^2p + q^3p = \frac{175}{256}$$

**Shorter way:**

We can look at the chance to miss the target on all four shots and then substract 1 to that result.

The chance to miss all four shots is: $q^4 = \frac{81}{256}$ so the chance to hit the target on at least one of the shots is $$1-q^4 = \frac{175}{256}$$

Comment: Hi,thanks for the answer, how the "long way" formula has come to action, is there a link for reference..?

Comment: @VellankiGaneshBabu I edited the solution so the explanation is clearer. Once you get to $p + qp + q^2p + q^3p$ you just have to substitute $p$ and $q$ for their values $1/4$ and $3/4$, respectively.